# Typescript: weird behavior on implementation of union of types

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this code.

```js
interface StateType<ExtendedBooleanType extends boolean, ExtendedLogType extends "is true" | "is false" | "both"> {
    bool: ExtendedBooleanType;
    log: ExtendedLogType,
}

type State =
    | StateType<true, "is true">
    | StateType<false, "is false">


const state: State = {
    bool: true,
    log: "is true"
}; // This runs and is expected, great!

const state: State = {
    bool: false,
    log: "is true"
}; // This doesn't run, and is expected, great!
```

But when I add this code, this doesn't work.

```js
type StateList =
    | StateType<true, "is true">[]
    | StateType<false, "is false">[]
    | StateType<true & false, "both">[]

const state_list: StateList = [
    { bool: true, log: "both" },
    { bool: false, log: "both" },
]; // This doesn't work, and I don't know why :T
```

Ideally the `StateList` would recognize that the list has both `true` and `false`, and hence the log should be "both", but I can't get it to work.

I want to get the compiler to realize 3 cases, when the list has only `true`'s, when the list has only `false`'s and when the list has both, and make that a type similar to `StateList`.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Keep in mind that intersection of true and false gives you `never`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get the compiler to realize that the list has both true and false, or only has false, or only has true.

Comment: What happens if you use `true | false` instead of `true & false`? As @captain-yossarian said, `true & false` becomes `never`, because it's not possible for something to be true and false at the same time.

Comment: The problem with `false | true` is that when they're all `false` or when they're all `true` `"both"` still is a possible value for log, but that shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 2):

`true & false` - gives you `never`. Type can't be `true` and at the same time `false`. Imagine number which can be `0` and at the same time `1`. It is impossible.

`StateList` type should not be a union type. It should be conditional type. You should treat it as a function which checks whether list contains both `true` and `false` or not.

Furthermore, `StateType` type allows you to create invalid state `StateType<true, "is false">` which is not cool.

If I were you, I would create a `BooleanMap`:

```js
type BooleanMap = {
    true: true,
    false: false
}
```

Now, we can iterate through each key of the map and create appropriate state.

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type BooleanState<
    T extends Record<string, boolean>
    > = Values<{
        [Prop in keyof T]: {
            bool: T[Prop],
            log: `is ${Prop & string}`
        }
    }>

// type State = {
//     bool: true;
//     log: "is true";
// } | {
//     bool: false;
//     log: "is false";
// }
type State = BooleanState<BooleanMap>
```

Result is the same as yours.
Ok, I know this is a bit verbose solution. Just wanted to show you this technique because some times it is very useful to make illegal state unrepresentable. I have used this pattern in several answers. See [this](https://catchts.com/callbacks#callback_in_union%202)

This solution is less verbose and uses power of [distributive-conditional-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```js
type MakeState<Bool extends boolean> =
    Bool extends true
    ? { bool: true, log: 'is true' }
    : { bool: false, log: 'is false' }

type State = MakeState<boolean>
```

If you want to express `false & true === 'both'`, you should not do it as a part of union. It should be done in a validation function/type.

Using `StateType<true & false, "both">[]` as a part of our list state is a bit tricky, because this type should represent result of our validate function. We should obtain it after some calculations. This type can't be self represented in TypeScript without using conditional types.

In order to validate `state_list` we need extra function.
Let's write a function and try to infer literal type of argument:

```js
const validation = <
    Elem extends State,
    Tuple extends Elem[]
>(tuple: [...Tuple]) => tuple

validation([
    { bool: true, log: "is true" },
    { bool: true, log: "is true" },
])
```

If you hover your mouse on `validation`, you will see that provided argument is infered. If you are interested in inference you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments). If you wonder what this syntax `[...Tuple]` means  - it is [variadic tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types).

Ok, lets proceed. Now, when we have each element in the tuple infered, we can write `Validate` type. If you are interested in type validation of function arguments in typescript, you can check my articles: [this](https://catchts.com/validators) and [this](https://catchts.com/type-negation).

```js
type TupleMap<T extends State[],Result extends any[]=[]>=
    T extends [] 
    ? Result
    : T extends [infer Head,...infer Tail]
    ? Head extends State
    ? Tail extends State[]
    ? TupleMap<Tail,[...Result,{bool:Head['bool'],log:'both'}]>
    : never
    :never
    :never

type Validation<Tuple extends any[]> =
    boolean extends Tuple[number]['bool']
    ? TupleMap<Tuple>
    : Tuple
```

`Validation` expects tuple of `State`. `boolean extends Tuple[number]['bool']` - means that if property `bool` of each element in the tuple is a union of `true | false` we need to remove `log` property and add another one with "both" value. In order to do it, we need to recursively iterate through each element in the tuple and override `log` property. [Here](https://catchts.com/tuples), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68207767/typescript-infer-possible-object-keys-based-on-value-of-previous-argument/68208487#68208487) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69299590/transform-array-of-objects-to-single-object-and-keep-types-in-typescript/69300965#69300965) you will find more explanation about tuple iteration.

Let's use `Validation` inside the function:

```js
type MakeState<Bool extends boolean> =
    Bool extends true
    ? { bool: true, log: 'is true' }
    : { bool: false, log: 'is false' }

type State = MakeState<boolean>

type EdgeCaseState = { bool: boolean, log: 'both' }


type TupleMap<T extends State[],Result extends any[]=[]>=
    T extends [] 
    ? Result
    : T extends [infer Head,...infer Tail]
    ? Head extends State
    ? Tail extends State[]
    ? TupleMap<Tail,[...Result,{bool:Head['bool'],log:'both'}]>
    : never
    :never
    :never

type Validation<Tuple extends any[]> =
    boolean extends Tuple[number]['bool']
    ? TupleMap<Tuple>
    : Tuple

const validation = <
    Elem extends State,
    Tuple extends Elem[]
>(tuple: Validation<[...Tuple]>) => tuple

validation([
    { bool: true, log: "is true" },
    { bool: true, log: "is true" },
]) // no errors

validation([
    { bool: false, log: "is false" }, // expected error
    { bool: true, log: "is true" }, // expected error
])

validation([
    { bool: false, log: "both" }, // ok
    { bool: true, log: "both" }, // ok
])
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N53M9W)

`TupleMap` is a little verbose utility. It is possible to refactor it and use less verbose version:

```js
type TupleMap<T extends State[]> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends State ? { bool: T[Prop]['bool'], log: 'both' } : never
}
```

I know what you are going to ask:

Q: Is it possible to get rid of extra function ?

A: No. Please see [this](https://catchts.com/rest-tuples) article. We need extra function in order to do validation.

Q: Is extra function affect code performance?

A: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66866683/do-we-have-any-guarantees-about-arrow-functions-optimization-in-js) answer.