# Create and use type from the keys of an object to check type on a chosen value from object

Tags: typescript

I have an object which consists of keys as strings, and value as strings. It looks like this:

```
const colors = {
  red: '#ff0000',
  green: '#00ff00',
  blue: '#0000ff',
}
```

I then create a type that accepts only the keys of an object. For example:

```
// Result: 'red' | 'green' | 'blue'
type ColorType = keyof typeof colors
```

Then, I want to use this type to check a value from a function that returns a value from `colors`. But it throws an error. For example:

```
const getColor = (color: ColorType): ColorType => {
  // This throws an error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"red" | "green" | "blue"'
  return colors[color]
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The result type of your function is not `ColorType` but `typeof colors[ColorType]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw, if you are interested in HEX type safety, you can try next approach:

```js
type HexNumber = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
type HexString = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f'
type StringNumber<T extends number> = `${T}`;
type HEX = HexNumber | StringNumber<HexNumber> | HexString;

type ToArray<T extends string, Cache extends readonly string[] = []> =
    T extends `${infer A}${infer Rest}`
    ? A extends HEX
    ? ToArray<Rest, [...Cache, A]> : A extends ''
    ? 1 : 2 : T extends '' ? Cache extends { length: 6 }
    ? Cache : 'String should have 6 chars. No more, no less' : never;

type Elem = string;

type ReduceToString<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>,
    Result extends string = ''
    > = Arr extends []
    ? Result
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? H extends Elem
    ? `${Result}${H}`
    : never
    : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
    ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>
    ? H extends Elem
    ? ReduceToString<Tail, `${Result}${H}`>
    : never
    : never
    : never;


const colors = {
    red: '#ff0000',
    green: '#00ff00',
    blue: '#0000ff',
} as const

type Colors = typeof colors;

type Tail<T extends string> = T extends `#${infer HEX}` ? HEX : never;

type ColorType = keyof typeof colors

type HexValidation<T extends keyof Colors> = ReduceToString<ToArray<Tail<Colors[T]>>>

function getColor<C extends keyof Colors>(color: C): HexValidation<C>
function getColor<C extends keyof Colors>(color: C) {
    return colors[color]
}

const result = getColor('red') // "ff0000"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhAeA5ArgWwEYQE5QLxQAYoAfKARhKgCZKBmSgFkoFZKA2SgdkoA5KBOAFChIsBAGVgWAJYA7AOZ4oAcgCCyysoBCG0soDCulQBEjygKJmAYmYCGZ9GYDGZgCZmIZgGbLh4aJIyCigY2AA8ACpQCMAQsq4AzlCyaJhYAHxKAAYAJADeEQC%20WQDcfqIw5gAaSnBIqdiUgXLyIWlhdW3YmaR1zQpl5dARAPaqWFi2IJHR8LHxSQlSLQA0UPq2TgAW0DFxiVBYELauI7IANiBQS0HyANoAukqPmbiCUB9QUXsLULl5ci8jVUhXygMaACUIEtiu9PgB%20KCqWbzA6VKpwj6I0bjSbTKFLNZ3AB0pI22wga1UD0yAC4kSj9kllL5PlBERR6TR6d85kyVBpEeSdozfnkoOc4vJgFt6RxCpj2etNiL6cp%20ooElsRshzq4oFtbAA3aAcba2LAJYlQRAjKCoEZHNayO2ShIJDT02QQE1YQYiaDmSWoJQ3Fr%20-xQKGuZBOCCjDVhRW40UHKEnM6XXFTMJBiCodIrRUE3XAVOLZYKJQsxWvJETctQR6KxEl87ARX0lM-A53cE4GAPFuwRt51DD-5t4CgvIwWFsr0%207Cd%20s4HtJI4Zi5XPuyIEDtak4n9r62aTnIds7Fn86N9OnbfZ6Zj9LDmCj4PD6Ox%20MjRMRG81knaFSxnOcslfBdkiXLAV29X04JgwZBCcM4ligVDzkdJJ8DyRUjlcNUAGIvC8AhyIIZQizZeQjjiYjyNI8iqMVdBzmQCAGIo0iWMKKBbCSVDZCWQQhnWEYsMtJQAxGLwMIk7CI1EADzxmddrkreQ615VEkiyIiwT3Rp0WKJV0SgRdfSU6B9AUrAIkjfAAGsIBAWSoBkuTMOw0SAzEeAADVbHOaRXFsYBpDONS%20V%20Fy3Lk2zJISOtvzjBNNMiMYJhzFTzjCRLsLuCIaXSV9BC8ZBZCcCKzigeQIGAAqsHyxs4vcprkoACm8rB6X0ABKek6iCkKwpq2R8tfCqqvGuqGqalr1LahK7K6nq%20v6qA8LZI5gGQLBZHkpK7h6ocFRQtCyyOBJSyUerGrszrlAI5RNoAejeqAACImIor7BCAA)

If you try to provide invalid HEX property in `colors` object, TS will throw an error.

[More explanation](https://catchts.com/hex-validation) you can find in my blog and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851513/a-way-to-mark-arbitrary-strings-in-typescript-template-literals#answer-66852494) answer