# How to create standalone type for a HEX color string?

Tags: typescript, colors, hex, typescript-generics, color-codes

I'm trying to create a standalone type in TypeScript that can be used to represent a single  valid HEX color code as a fully type-safe string.

My attempt is below, which falls short due to not actually being a standalone type, which is what I would hope to achieve.

```
type HexDigit<T extends '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e'| 'f' | 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E'| 'F'> = T;
type HexColor<T extends string> =
    T extends `#${HexDigit<infer D1>}${HexDigit<infer D2>}${HexDigit<infer D3>}${HexDigit<infer D4>}${HexDigit<infer D5>}${HexDigit<infer D5>}`
        ? T
        : (
            T extends `#${HexDigit<infer D1>}${HexDigit<infer D2>}${HexDigit<infer D3>}`
            ? T
            : never
        );

function hex<T extends string>(s: HexColor<T>): T {
    return s;
}

// All valid
hex('#ffffff');
hex('#fff');
hex('#000');
hex('#123456');
hex('#abcdef');
hex('#012def');
hex('#ABCDEF');
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200924#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhAeARAlgc2cAPAFSg4EAdgCYDOUA5AAwVQA+lAjLQxQEwuUDMnFALLwCsvAGy8A7LwAcvAJy8AhrwBGvAMa9ivCBVYAzXgEFeAIV4BhXol4BRXZQBiFAHxQAvFGwBuAFChIsAjmAPYANsEATjh48AQk5KTAEciEqK5uPlBZnjFxZFAABgDEACQA3nBIaBiYKXoQEVCIjM4AvuWVKOhYdQ1NbG0dCF01vY2IXIMVw9U9hPXjfFOds7XzfYiCyzPdawtNW60FmdmnAPyeJ6dZAFxQABRX16e4+ET5xUNVu2NNLe3Tb6jdbjAYAlY-EFNSZHJ7PLIXbBw+F3QgQABuDWRWQAlL4fHoAK6ENTAZDBQhQAAWCGib3iUESyVSznupDulRC4Si2GcOLuuDKTwiEGAhIilNIvlaPh8AHo5VBDKFQlB0QpQshiD4afB7hQinojcaKHidQh9YajabfLrLVQHTbzXqDYw2Fw+IIxGa7QaFMo1MQIAYfRaDVQ3UGQ7aw0VDCZzIgbE48UA)

Trying to use a type with a generic as a standalone type was bound to fail, so I got stuck at this point.

```
// Ideal use case - does not compute
const color: HexColor = '#aaa';
const theme: Record<string, HexColor> = {
    backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
    color: '#0f0',
};
```

Is this even possible to achieve with TypeScript, and if so, how?

Comment: does the code posted in your question work? i copy pasted it into ts playground, but i am getting a `Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent` error

Comment: @RitikMishra I edited my playground link into the question where I saw this code working, I hope that helps.

Comment: Very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851513/a-way-to-mark-arbitrary-strings-in-typescript-template-literals#answer-66852494  and more explanation in my blog https://catchts.com/hex-validation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably already tried to do it the naive way, where you make a union of all the possibilites, and [it does actually work for a three-digit hex color, but not for a longer one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgczsKBeKByADBqAfTARlwIwCYTMBmSjAFloFZaA2WgdloA5aBOWgIa0ARrQDGtACa0IGUgDNaAQVoAhWgGFaMWgFFaAMQwBuAFChIUAMoALAPYAnYBrsAbR2igADAMQASAG94JGAAX0Dg5HCgxCivMwtoABk7ADsEF3cHT18I2LC8kOjIgpiiwqiKsPjzcGhMj3RbR2c3DwIU9IaHM1MxNIBnFAG7AFsIboAua3snbs8MH3kxCjN%201KGoYQFJKZmW%20fRFsQRVoA) (see code below). I suspect, to answer your question directly, that it's impossible to make a 'standalone' type that works for all six-digit hex colors, because this would have to be a union of millions of elements.

```
type Digit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e'| 'f' | 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F';
type ShortColor = `#${Digit}${Digit}${Digit}`;
type LongColor = `#${Digit}${Digit}${Digit}${Digit}${Digit}${Digit}`;  // Error
type Color = ShortColor | LongColor;

const someColor: ShortColor = '#fc2';
const badColor: ShortColor = '#cg2';  // Error
```

That said, I think your solution is a fine one itself. I did notice your code doesn't work on newer versions of TypeScript, so [I made a slight modification to it so that it does work with the latest version, 4.4.0-beta](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta&ssl=25&ssc=16&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhAeARAlgc2cAPAFSg4EAdgCYDOUA5AAwVQA%20lAjLQxQEwuUDMnFALLwCsvAGy8A7LwAcvAJy8AhrwBGvAMa9ivCBVYAzXgEFeAIV4BhXol4BRXZQBiFAHxQAvFGwBuAFChIsAjmAPYANsEATjh48AQk5KTAEciEqK5uPlBZnjFxZFAABgDEACQA3nBIaBiYKXoQEVCIjM4AvuWVKOhYdQ1NbG0dCF01vY2IXINlY1AAShCJjK0FmdlrAPxQABTzi7lE%20QUFUKtrZ1CbuAD0V1DAABYREBAAtMTVwFD3CFBqYZGnc7ZABc20BQLOu2AjH28UKQyq3VqhHq4z4U06H2RqKaggxwyxM0QIjaKwh5OylyyNygpGQ8DeHy%20Pz%204Qi4IpZ1BhAgADcGhzzgBKQVQEUQ7l8hq%20Hx6ACuhDUwGQwUIzPg0XwBwSSRSaS2pFBlRCbJwziFoNwZUBT2AcoiatIvlaPh8NMMoVCUF5ClCyGIPm%208C2FCKenDEYoQt8QZDYfDUZjCDjVFTicDydDjDYXD4gjE0YzwdDCmUamIEAMhdjoao2YrVaTxaKhhM5kQNic0aAA). The code is a bit simpler and avoids generating too large of a union by doing the conditional check in two steps:

```
type HexDigit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e'| 'f' | 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E'| 'F';
type HexColor<T extends string> =
    T extends `#${HexDigit}${HexDigit}${HexDigit}${infer Rest1}`
        ? (Rest1 extends `` 
            ? T // three-digit hex color
            : (
                Rest1 extends `${HexDigit}${HexDigit}${HexDigit}`
                    ? T  // six-digit hex color
                    : never
            )
        )
        : never;

function hex<T extends string>(s: HexColor<T>): T {
    return s;
}

// All valid
hex('#ffffff');
hex('#fff');
hex('#000');
hex('#123456');
hex('#abcdef');
hex('#012def');
hex('#ABCDEF');
```

Finally, I might suggest that you use [type brands](https://michalzalecki.com/nominal-typing-in-typescript/#approach-4-intersection-types-and-brands) to create a type which signifies that a string is a valid hex color, and only use your `hex` function to create strings of that type? In the example below, you could simply use `Color` throughout your codebase and only need to rely on the `hex` helper function when specifically making a `Color` from a string literal for the first time. I don't know if this'll meet your exact ideal usecase, because you do still need to use your `hex` helper wherever a literal is declared, but it gets you pretty close:

```
type Color = string & { __type: "HexColor" };
function hex<T extends string>(s: HexColor<T>): Color {
    return s;
}

const color: Color = hex('#aaa');
const theme: Record<string, Color> = {
    backgroundColor: hex('#ff0000'),
    color: hex('#0f0'),
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated explanation. can you add the implementation of HexColorValidator?

Comment: Sorry @yuval.bl, that was just a typo. I've updated the post to correctly say `HexColor` instead now!