# How to use spread operator in typescript as argument to a function?

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to spread the array in to the argment of the function,
but I am getting A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)

```js
  const currentColor: string = context.brandingPersonal.customColor; // rgba string 
  const numberColor: [number, number, number, number] = currentColor
    .substring(5, currentColor.length - 1)
    .replace(/ /g, '')
    .split(',')
    .map((item) => Number(item));

  function getContrastColor(R: number, G: number, B: number, A?: number) {
    const brightness = R * 0.299 + G * 0.587 + B * 0.114 + (1 - A || 0) * 255;
    return brightness > 186 ? '#000000' : '#FFFFFF';
  }
  getContrastColor(...numberColor);
```

Comment: TS doesn't know that `numberColor`'s type is a "tuple" (a fixed size array in TS) because tuples need to be defined as const. Add `as const` after `[255,50,50,0.1]` to narrow the type from Array<Number> to [Number, Number, Number, Number]

Comment: The problem is that the function has a fixed number of parameters, an array does not. You can turn it into a tuple, make the array const, or use `rest` (which IMO maybe don't). Searching the web for the error message may provide other options, too.

Comment: @HKG what if the value is rgb only how to set the last parameter optional in the argument ?

Comment: Simply by doing `A?: number`

Comment: @HKG I will update my code to show you what is going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type) you can find explanation of creating number range in typescript.

[Here](https://catchts.com/range-numbers) you can find my article about creating number range.

It is possible to achieve extra safety with static type analysis:

```js
type MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY = 256

type ComputeRange<
    N extends number,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends N
        ? Result
        : ComputeRange<N, [...Result, Result['length']]>
    )

type Octal = ComputeRange<MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY>[number]

type Digits = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9

type AlphaChanel = `0.${Digits}` | '1.0'

type RGBA<Alpha extends number = 1.0> = [Octal, Octal, Octal, (`${Alpha}` extends AlphaChanel ? Alpha : never)?]

function getContrastColor<Alpha extends number>(...[R, G, B, a]: RGBA<Alpha>) {
    const A = a || 1;

    const brightness = R * 0.299 + G * 0.587 + B * 0.114 + (1 - A || 0) * 255;

    return brightness > 186 ? '#000000' : '#FFFFFF';
}

getContrastColor(10, 20, 30, 0.2); // ok
getContrastColor(256, 20, 30, 0.2); // error, 256 is out of the range
getContrastColor(255, 20, 30, 0.22); // error, 0.22 should be 0.2
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbG78W)

`RGBA` utility type acts as a type validator and at the same time as a type for all valid RGB tuples. You can find more info [here](https://catchts.com/validators) and [here](https://catchts.com/type-negation). If `A` is allowed alpha channel value it returns `A`, otherwise - `never`.

`AlphaChanel` - is a union of all allowed values. As you might have noticed I have allowed only one digit after `0.`. If you want to allow more, please use this:

```js
type AlphaChanel = `0.${ComputeRange<999>[number]}` | '1.0'
```

If you are interested in `hex` validation, you can check [this](https://catchts.com/hex-validation) article or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851513/a-way-to-mark-arbitrary-strings-in-typescript-template-literals#answer-66852494) answer

Answer (score 1):

How about using tuples?

```js
const numberColor = [255,50,50,0.1]

// Check RGBA
function getContrastColor([ R, G, B, A ]:[number, number, number, number]) {
  const brightness = R * 0.299 + G * 0.587 + B * 0.114 + (1 - A) * 255;

  return brightness > 186 ? '#000000' : '#FFFFFF';
}

// function call with spread operator 
getContrastColor(numberColor);
```

Comment: The problem is i want it to support both rgba and rgb so i could have 3 number or 4 numbers

Comment: Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number, number, number]'.
  Target requires 4 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2345)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

`split` makes no guarantees about how many pieces it'll output at runtime. Passing a string like "foo" would make your routine fail, because your function would not return a valid 4-tuple.

You could use something like this, which guarantees a proper tuple output:

```js
function getNumberTuple(color: string) : [number, number, number, number?] {
  const rgba = color.substring(5, color.length - 1).replace(/ /g, "")
  const numbers = rgba.split(",").map((item) => Number(item));
  return [numbers[0] || 0, numbers[1] || 0, numbers[2] || 0, numbers[3]]
}

function getContrastColor(R: number, G: number, B: number, A?: number) { /* ... */}

getContrastColor(...getNumberTuple("color 123,123,123"));
```