# Making a Dynamic callable typescript interface property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This is the part of palette, i am using a `IPalette` interface right here:

```
{
  warningColor: '#FFCA28',
  smallWidgetBackground: ["rgba(255,255,255,0.15)", "rgba(255,255,255,0)"],
  grayColorAlpha: (opacity: number) => `rgba(200, 209, 232, ${opacity})`,
  welcome: {
    primaryText: "#fff",
    primaryTextAlpha: (alpha = 1) => `rgba(255,255,255,${alpha})`,
  },
}
```

And the problem is that I want to create an interface with dynamic properties, both for keys as a string, and if the key is callable as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this exmaple:

```js
type RGBA = `rgba(${number}, ${number}, ${number}, ${number})`

type Alpha = (opacity: number) => RGBA

type KeysHex = `${string}Color` | `${string}Text`

interface Data {
  [color: KeysHex]: `#${string}`
  [alpha: `${string}Alpha`]: Alpha
}

const foo: Data = {
  criticalColor: '2' // expected error
}

const bar: Data = {
  criticalColor: '#2' // ok, there is a limitation in TS
}

const baz: Data = {
  criticalColorAlpha: (opacity: number) => `rgba(1, 1, 1, ${opacity})` // ok
}

const baz2: Data = {
  criticalColorAlpha: (opacity: number) => `rgba(1, 1, 1, x)` // expected error
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WPZYLN)

I have noticed, that you are using `Alpha` suffix if this is a method and `Color` or `Text` if it is a HEX color. This is why I have decided to use two different keys for `Data` interface.

You can use stonger types for `RGBA` but there is a limitation. Please see my [article](https://catchts.com/range-numbers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70717701/how-to-use-spread-operator-in-typescript-as-argument-to-a-function#answer-70720851) answer.

The same story about HEX colors. Please see [this](https://catchts.com/hex-validation) article.

Please provide all scenarios or restrictions and I will try to provide you with the most safest type.

Thank you

**UPDATE**
The syntax you have used in your comment:

```js
  [key in AdditionalKeysHex]:`#${string}`|string[];
```

is wrong. You are allowed to use `in` operator only in mapped types. In order to achieve desired behavior, I think `Data` interface should be splitted.

Please see `DataResult` type:

```js
type RGBA = `rgba(${number}, ${number}, ${number}, ${number})`

type Alpha = (opacity: number) => RGBA

type KeysHex = `${string}Color` | `${string}Text` | `${string}Icon` | `${string}Background`;

const arr = ['white', 'darkGrayBlue', 'secondDarkGrayBlue', 'thirdDarkGrayBlue', 'darkDullBlue', 'secondDarkDullBlue', 'lightGrayBlue', 'secondLightGrayBlue', 'thirdLightGrayBlue', 'fourthLightGrayBlue', 'fifthLighGrayBlue', 'lightGrayNavy', 'paleNavy', 'brightBlue']

type AdditionalKeysHex = 'white' | 'darkGrayBlue' | 'secondDarkGrayBlue' | 'thirdDarkGrayBlue' | 'darkDullBlue' | 'secondDarkDullBlue' | 'lightGrayBlue' | 'secondLightGrayBlue' | 'thirdLightGrayBlue' | 'fourthLightGrayBlue' | 'fifthLighGrayBlue' | 'lightGrayNavy' | 'paleNavy' | 'brightBlue';

interface IWelcome {
  [color: KeysHex]: `#${string}` | string[];
  [alpha: `${string}Alpha`]: Alpha;
}


type WithKey = {
  [key in AdditionalKeysHex]: `#${string}` | string[];

}

interface Data {
  [color: KeysHex]: `#${string}` | string[];
  [alpha: `${string}Alpha`]: Alpha;
  welcome: IWelcome;
}

type DataResult = WithKey & Data

const Palette: DataResult = {
  primaryText: "#58585B",
  secondaryText: "#39393B",
  secondaryIcon: "#C8D1E8",
  tertiaryText: "#8F8E94",
  smallWidgetBackground: ["rgba(255,255,255,0.15)", "rgba(255,255,255,0)"],
  grayColorAlpha: (opacity: number) => `rgba(200, 209, 232, ${opacity})`,
  primaryTextAlpha: (opacity: number = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
  welcome: {
    primaryText: "#fff",
    primaryTextAlpha: (opacity: number = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
    secondaryText: "#C8D1E8",
    loaderColor: "#fff",
  },
  white: '#FFFFFF',
  darkGrayBlue: '#363C52',
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mp9r6W)

Comment: You can add `Icon` to `KeysHex`. Do you have a naming pattern ?

Comment: @Olek I will back in several hours. Sorry

Comment: Yes, thank you! This is what I come up with, only got issues from a non-KeysHex pattern key : https://tsplay.dev/wOP9zN

Comment: @Olek I made an update

Comment: @Olek Героям Слава! Thank you for your support!

Comment: I'm also Ukrainian. Currently in Odesa:)

Comment: @Olek it is nice to hear. Wish you silent night

Comment: Wish you the same!)

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the specific keys:

```
export type AlphaColorProcessing = (opacity: number) => string;

export interface Styles {
  [key: string]: string | AlphaColorProcessing;
}
```

Comment: This is what i did at the first time, error that I got:

This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'string | string[] | welcomeMapping | alphaColorProcessing' are callable.
    Type 'string' has no call signatures

Comment: this makes the keys optional which might not be what OP wants

Comment: how are you using it, u can add a typeguard before calling the styling