# Is there a way to keep the value an object refers to as a string reference key and not the actual value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, reference

Given this code:

```
const colors = {
  WHITE: "#FFF",
};
const style = {
  backgroundColor: colors.WHITE,
};
```

Throughout my code when I access `style.backgroundColor` I want the value to be `"#FFF"` as expected. But at a specific point I would like to know the reference key path as a string. For instance, I want the value to be `"colors.WHITE"`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No. The expression `colors.WHITE` is evaluated when your `style` object is built, and after that the only thing left is the value of that expression (`"#FFF"`). If you want to "remember" the entry in your `colors` object, store that as a separate property.

Comment: Best you could do is `as const` for them, and then you'll be able to type-check that `colors.WHITE` is the same as `style.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it might be toooo much, but you can try this:

```js
type ComputeRange<
    N extends number,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends N
        ? Result[number]
        : ComputeRange<N, [...Result, Result['length']]>
    )

type HexNumber = `${ComputeRange<10>}`
type HexString = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f'

type Hex = `${HexNumber}` | HexString;

type StringLength<
    Str extends string,
    Acc extends string[] = []
    > =
    (Str extends `${infer S}${infer Rest}`
        ? StringLength<Rest, [...Acc, S]>
        : Acc['length'])

type ValidateLength<
    Str extends string,
    Length extends number
    > =
    (StringLength<Str> extends Length
        ? Str
        : never)

type ValidateHex<
    Color extends string,
    Cache extends string = '',
    > =
    Color extends `${infer A}${infer Rest}`
    ? (A extends ''
        ? Cache
        : (A extends Hex
            ? ValidateHex<Rest, `${Cache}${A}`>
            : never)
    ) : Cache


type ExtractHash<T extends string> = T extends `#${infer Rest}` ? Rest : never


type ValidateMap<T extends Record<string, string>> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] & ValidateHex<T[Prop]> & ValidateLength<T[Prop], 6 | 3>
}

type AddHash<T extends Record<string, string>> = { [Prop in keyof T]: `#${T[Prop]}` }


const color = <
    Key extends string,
    Value extends string,
    ColorMap extends Record<Key, Value>
>(dictionary: AddHash<ValidateMap<ColorMap>>) => dictionary


const colorTheme = color({
    white: '#ffffff',
    gray: '#e2e2e2',
    green: '#ffx' // expected error

})

colorTheme.gray // '#e2e2e2'
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1pnGW)

**Pros:**

TS will validate your hex value

**Cons:**

You need to create dummy runtime function for inference validation.

If you are interested in this solution I will provide some explanation.

Meanwhile, you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/hex-validation#function_inference) and related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851513/a-way-to-mark-arbitrary-strings-in-typescript-template-literals#answer-66852494)